# Spring boot dynamic update in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

Is it possible to dynamically update the document? 
Otherwise, for example I have if I have UserProfie as

```
UserProfile {
    String name
    String lastName
    Object Address
    String token
}
```

Then I'm looking to create about 3 endpoints just for this Document. But if I can do dynamic update then I'll be doing one method.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing via variable,  you accumulate your update information into a `Map`

```
Map<String, Object> updateInfo; // Key is db column name, value is updatedValue
```

Then create dynamic update operations:

```
UpdateOperations<Entity> updateOps = datastore.createUpdateOperations(Entity.class);

updateInfo.entrySet().forEach(e -> updateOps.set(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
```

Now you can use this `updateOps` to update your document dynamically.

Comment: Explain more please. Where do those methods come from? What imports?
What do you mean by map<string, object>? Can you provide a concrete example please?

Comment: You're using Spring data mongo?

Comment: Yes I am. Where does datastore comes from?